# Visual Studio Code Prettier plugin for Apex not formatting VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, vs-code, visualstudiocode, format

I've been using VSC for ages now and have had the apex Prettier plugin installed and working, but it is no longer formatting my Visualforce pages (it's still doing it for apex classes).

I now get this message showing up:
[image]

This is what displays in the right corner for the VF page:
[image]

but for apex code it displays this:
[image]

I had a look at [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/320884/use-prettier-in-vs-code-to-format-visualforce) page, but that doesn't work for me and doesn't seem to be the right solution? Can anyone help me?

The .prettierrc file:

```
{
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "**/lwc/**/*.html",
      "options": { "parser": "lwc" }
    },
    {
      "files": "*.{cmp,page,component}",
      "options": { "parser": "html" }
    }
  ]
}
```

and my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "salesforce-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Salesforce App",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "npm run lint:lwc && npm run lint:aura",
    "lint:aura": "eslint **/aura/**",
    "lint:lwc": "eslint **/lwc/**",
    "test": "npm run test:unit",
    "test:unit": "sfdx-lwc-jest",
    "test:unit:watch": "sfdx-lwc-jest --watch",
    "test:unit:debug": "sfdx-lwc-jest --debug",
    "test:unit:coverage": "sfdx-lwc-jest --coverage",
    "prettier": "prettier --write \"**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}\"",
    "prettier:verify": "prettier --list-different \"**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prettier/plugin-xml": "^0.12.0",
    "@salesforce/eslint-config-lwc": "^0.7.0",
    "@salesforce/eslint-plugin-aura": "^1.4.0",
    "@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "^0.9.2",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.0.7",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "prettier-plugin-apex": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "**/{aura|lwc}/**": [
      "eslint"
    ]
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**UPDATE**: The workaround I'm having to use is to manually format a VF page by entering the below into the TERMINAL tab, but I have to do this for each VF page/cmp I edit:

```
yarn prettier --write salesforce/src/main/default/pages/AccountHolderRules.page
```

Comment: Can you share the `packge.json` and `.prettierrc`

Comment: I've added both files above.

Answer (score 0):

There is another plugin called 'Beautify'. You can add that from Extensions. After installing that relaunch the VS Code. Then,

1. Open your file
2. Press ctrl+shift+p
3. Type 'Beautify File' in the search box and select it
4. Select 'HTML' from out of the three options which are getting populated

Comment: Does that format in the same way as Prettier?

Comment: @Irene I have not used pretier before. Hence I am not too sure about that. Generally I am using this plugin to format my code

Comment: Okay - I've just tested and it formats differently. Similar, but different, and it means I can't use it because the code validation prior to our deploy process checks that the formatting is Prettier.

Comment: @Irene oh okay. Got it